# Почему malloc() большого количества данных не приводит к ошибке?

Tags: c++, linux, c, malloc

У меня скорее вопрос, чем проблема. `malloc()` не выводит ошибки, если я пытаюсь выделить 8GB памяти, но на ноутбуке её всего 6GB. Как такое возможно?

Comment: Если функции не удалось выделить требуемый блок памяти, возвращается нулевой указатель.

Comment: Странность в том, что она не возвращает NULL.

Comment: Виртуальная память?

Comment: С учетом swap памяти у вас хватает. Выделяется ведь виртуальная память, которая вполне может быть больше, чем реальный RAM. Хотя, следует сказать про одну неприятную особенность Линукса. В самом деле, он может выделить процессам значительно больше памяти, чем сможет потом реально предоставить.В определенный момент страниц виртуальной памяти (в т.ч. с учетом swap) может не хватить для маппирования в уже выделенную память. В таком случае выбирается (довольно случаная) жертва. Этот процесс принудительно завершается ядром и его уже реально выделенная память (страницы в RAM) освобождаются.

Comment: Что значит "на ноутбуке ее всего 6gb"? Вы запретили swap в вашей ОС?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Во-первых, максимальный размер доступной для выделения памяти не имеет никакого отношения к размеру установленного в вашем компьютере ОЗУ. Размер ограничен лишь размером адресного пространства процесса. Почитайте о том, как работают платформы с виртуальной памятью.

Во-вторых, в конфигурации по умолчанию ОС типа Linux допускают т.наз. "overcommit", т.е. спокойно позволяют пользователю распределять регионы адресного пространства процесса даже если физических ресурсов машины (ОЗУ и размера swap области) недостаточно для хранения такого объема данных. Физическая "материализация" выделенной памяти происходит постранично, не в момент выполнения `malloc`, а намного позже - тогда, когда вы начнете заполнять эту память своими данными. Вот именно при заполнении очередной страницы данными вы в определенный момент можете наткнуться на нехватку физических ресурсов для "материализации" этой страницы и ваша программа "упадет". Сам же `malloc` ничего фактически не делает, кроме пометки региона адресного пространства как занятого.

Таким образом тот факт, что `malloc` вам что-то позволил выделить, еще ничего не значит. `malloc` почти ничего не делает. Для того, чтобы убедиться, что ваше выделение памяти действительно "удалось", вам надо еще записать в *весь* выделенный блок памяти какие-то данные.

Comment: Добавлю, что именно поэтому - что выделение всегда якобы успешно, а потом использование выделенной памяти валит программу - Саттер в своих "Сложных задачах" говорит о *практической* бессмысленности перехвата исключения из `new`, и что лучшее, что можно сделать при этом перехвате - просто завершить программу.

Answer (score 6):

Происходит, так называемый overcommit. Эта настройка регулируется файлом `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`. Значение 0 (по умолчанию) включает некую эвристику, значение 1 всегда разрешает перевыделение памяти, значение 2 отключает такое поведение. В последнем случае проверка доступности памяти происходит после достижения CommitLimit при каждом вызове [**mmap**(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man2/mmap.2.html). Примечание: [**malloc**(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man3/malloc.3posix.html) в свой реализации использует [**mmap**(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man2/mmap.2.html) при необходимости расширения памяти процесса. Подробнее см. страницу руководства [**proc**(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/proc.5.html).

Вы можете даже провести эксперимент. Отключите overcommit и попытайтесь запустить вашу тестовую программу.

```
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Comment: `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` -- частенько в стандартных дистрибутивах после этого новые процессы перестают запускаться.